# SAPUI5 how to make sap.m.Wizard handles more than 8 Steps

Tags: sapui5, wizard

Is there please any way to make the sap.m.Wizard be able to handle more than 8 Steps or is there any alternative to this control? Actually it does not shows the others Steps when I put more than 8.

thank you very much for any tip.

Regards

Aline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the source code of the sap.m.Wizard: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Wizard.js

There is a constant that limits the number of steps to 8 (as you've already found out).

This constant is used in the method `Wizard.prototype._isMaxStepCountExceeded`. This method is then used in `Wizard.prototype.addStep`.

I see 3 possibilities. 2 of them include subclassing the Wizard:

- Override the constant `Wizard.CONSTANTS.MAXIMUM_STEPS` in your subclass to a value greater than 8.
- Override the `addStep` method in your subclass so unlimited steps are possible.
- If branching is enabled, the Wizard ignores the constant `MAXIMUM_STEPS`. But this does not seem like a good solution to me, because it would require changing each WizardStep in your XML.

---

**Edit:** Here is a complete subclassing example

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/m/Wizard"
], function(Wizard) {
    "use strict";

    return Wizard.extend("mynamespace.InfiniteWizard", {

        renderer: {},

        addStep: function (wizardStep) {
            this._incrementStepCount();
            return this.addAggregation("steps", wizardStep);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Marc, thank you very much vor the very helpfull answer. I encounteres some issues trying to implement your solutions. Here is how i tried to implement it. Somehow it is not working<pre>`enter code here`

Comment: @Aline. Can you post your code on some external paste tool? Like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: hier is the link. [link](https://pastebin.com/zfV89dNw) . Then I used the namespace "custom:CustomWizard" in my XML view.

Comment: @Aline I just made a new project and did the subclass myself, see the edit I made. It seems as if you are missing basic concepts. Have you tried the UI5 walkthrough?

Comment: is it so obvious? :) Can you please send me the link to the new project?  I made the example based on the UI5 walkthrough.

Comment: thank you very much, Its work properly. I thought you where talking about editing my code on "pastebin". Still dont understand why they do limit the number of steps.